# How to test code coverage for Unlocked Packages when data cannot be inserted?

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, deployment, winter21

I am running into an issue related to SFDX packaging and was hoping you could help me.

To provide some context: I am using the ServiceChannel object for some tests related to PendingServiceRouting, AgentWork, and so on.

After creating a case with SF I was told that this object cannot be inserted through DML and only directly on the UI.

I found out that we can indeed create this, not from the test class, but using sfdx:force:data command (example: `sfdx force:data:record:create -s ServiceChannel -v "RelatedEntity=Case DeveloperName=CaseTest MasterLabel=CaseTest"`). So far so good.

However, after the Winter 21 release, it is now [mandatory to have a minimum of 75% code coverage in order to promote a package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_code_coverage.htm). Since it is not possible to create data for the scratch org where the tests will be run (since it's automated by SF), the tests are failing because no record exists on the scratch org and therefore I am unable to promote a package.

Is there any parameter that we can add to populate this data? It appears a little counter-intuitive that we cannot insert it but SF needs it to be present to allow the package to be released.

Best regards and thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you need the [Specify Unpackaged Metadata for Package Version Creation Tests (Pilot)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_sfdx_packaging_path_unpackaged_md.htm). This is the solution for most types of metadata that can't be packaged and is necessary for a test.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you for answering! Then again, that unpackagedMetadata property is to specify metadata only, right? Not the records themselves? Because the issue is not that ServiceChannel doesn't exist, but rather than the data is not on the spin-off scratch org (?) created during this process of testing in order to release the package.

Comment: ServiceChannel is a metadata item, right? You can include it in your package, or using the pilot feature.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your explanation (sorry if that is the case), but the issue is not related to the fact that ServiceChannel object is not present on the scratch org. The issue is that at least one ServiceChannel record is needed and there is no way to create it during this "package-promotion-apex-test-running" process.

Comment: Correct. You can include a ServiceChannel as part of the package. ServiceChannel "records" are not ordinary records, like Accounts or Contacts, but rather metadata records.

Comment: Oh, that changes everything :) Awesome will apply for the pilot! Thanks again for the help @sfdcfox!